# How to use both binary and continuous features in the k-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, knn

My feature vector has both continuous (or widely ranging) and binary components.  If I simply use Euclidean distance, the continuous components will have a much greater impact:

Representing symmetric vs. asymmetric as 0 and 1 and some less important ratio ranging from 0 to 100, changing from symmetric to asymmetric has a tiny distance impact compared to changing the ratio by 25.

I can add more weight to the symmetry (by making it 0 or 100 for example), but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using the normalized Euclidean distance, described, for example, at the end of the first section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

It simply scales every feature (continuous or discrete) by its standard deviation. This is more robust than, say, scaling by the range (`max-min`) as suggested by another poster.

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understand your question, normalizing (aka 'rescaling) each dimension or column in the data set is the conventional technique for dealing with over-weighting dimensions, e.g.,

```
ev_scaled = (ev_raw - ev_min) / (ev_max - ev_min)
```

In R, for instance, you can write this function:

```
ev_scaled = function(x) {
    (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
}
```

which works like this:

```
# generate some data: 
# v1, v2 are two expectation variables in the same dataset 
# but have very different 'scale':
> v1 = seq(100, 550, 50)
> v1
  [1] 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500 550
> v2 = sort(sample(seq(.1, 20, .1), 10))
> v2
  [1]  0.2  3.5  5.1  5.6  8.0  8.3  9.9 11.3 15.5 19.4
> mean(v1)
  [1] 325
> mean(v2)
  [1] 8.68

# now normalize v1 & v2 using the function above:
> v1_scaled = ev_scaled(v1)
> v1_scaled
  [1] 0.000 0.111 0.222 0.333 0.444 0.556 0.667 0.778 0.889 1.000
> v2_scaled = ev_scaled(v2)
> v2_scaled
  [1] 0.000 0.172 0.255 0.281 0.406 0.422 0.505 0.578 0.797 1.000
> mean(v1_scaled)
  [1] 0.5
> mean(v2_scaled)
  [1] 0.442
> range(v1_scaled)
  [1] 0 1
> range(v2_scaled)
  [1] 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) instead of Euclidean.